# Proper way to install/run a gradle plugin from github (specifically the arquilian plugin)?

Tags: gradle

I would like to use the arquillian plugin here to run jetty 8+:

https://github.com/aslakknutsen/arquillian-gradle-plugin

If I put "apply plugin: 'arquillian'" in my gradle script, it does not find it.

So I must have to install it somehow. I look for info on this, but did not find.

Would you have a pointer on how to do that?

I am using gradle 1.6 on windows.

---

**Update** after answer by @raeffs:
I updated the gradle script with it and the build is successfull, but I don't see my war started after an arquillianRunJetty (port 8080 is not even listening).

Then I tried to add what is indicated on the github page:

```
arquillian {
    debug = true
    deployable = file('my/path/arbitraryWebApp.war')

    containers {
        jetty {
            version = '8'
            type = 'embedded'
            config = ['bindHttpPort': 8080, 'bindAddress': '127.0.0.1', 'jettyPlus': false]

            dependencies {
                adapter 'org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-jetty-embedded-7:1.0.0.CR2'
                container 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.11.v20130520'
                container group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-plus', version: '8.1.11.v20130520'
            }
        }
```

I had to replace arquillian-jetty-embedded-7:1.0.0.CR2 with CR1 as it is not in maven central.

Then I put the path to my war. When starting again, there is more chatter but still no listening on port 8080.

So I still miss something.

I also find awkward to have to reference with an absolute path for the war I am building with the gradle script. I think there could be a kind of self reference.

**Update**
It is running fine now thanks to @raeffs. I don't really know what was wrong in my previous step.

The path to the web app takes the name, plus the version.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The creator of the plugin has not published it to a maven repository, so you have to build it on your own.

Get a local copy of the plugin project and build it. You should get a the 'arquillian-gradle-plugin-0.1.jar' as output.

In the build script of yout own project you have to declare a dependency to that jar. Add the following to your build script:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree(dir: '/path/to/folder/that/contains/the/jar',
            includes: ['arquillian-gradle-plugin-0.1.jar'])
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use the plugin.

**Update**

If you do not want to provide a hardcoded path to your deployable you could simply pass a variable. For example if you are using the war plugin:

```
arquillian {
    deployable = war.archivePath
}
```

Here is an example of the usage: https://gist.github.com/raeffs/5920562#file-build-gradle

It starts the jetty container, deploys the war and waits until ctrl+c is pressed.

Comment: Thanks, the build worked but still my war is not deployed - I updated my question if you want to follow.

Comment: I tried what you describe in your update and it works. I will publish my code on github tomorrow. Maybe that helps you out. I also updated my answer so you do not have to use an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working fine. I guess Jetty is installed dynamically, do you know where (unfortunatelly I am stuck with Windows and have limited search capabilities on that OS)

Comment: Gradle saves all the dependencies in c:\users\yourUser\.gralde\caches, this includes the Jetty jar. Maybe Jetty gets started from there, but I am not sure.